Turning off "New tag collected: Empty tag" popup when holding OnePlus 12 next to OnePlus Watch 2?
I have the following hardware with software:

OnePlus 12 phone, model CPH2583: Android 14, OxygenOS CPH2583_14.0.0.802(EX01)
OnePlus Watch 2, model OPWWE231: Android 13, WearOS V6.0

I have NFC turned on my phone and watch, since I regularly use tap-to-pay and Google Wallet. However, when I place my phone near my watch (for example, holding the phone in landscape with the hand that has my watch on it, leading to the NFC reader in the phone getting close to the watch), a "New tag collected" screen pops up:

I do not wish to turn off NFC on either device since I use both my phone and my watch for tap-to-pay. Is there a way to turn off this pop-up?
